# restart autoref of equation list from 1, 2 ... in an appendix of an apa6 document

Tags: hyperref, apa6

How to set up a separate array of equation labels in the Appendix as different from the ones used in the main text? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\oneappendixfalse
\begin{document}

The first equation is \autoref{e1}

\begin{equation}\label{e1}
x+y=z
\end{equation}

\appendix
\section{} %% another question is how to make this unused section line disappear

The first equation in Appendix A should be Equation A1 instead of \autoref{e2}

\begin{equation}\label{e2}
x+y=z
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Have you tried running `\setcounter{equation}{0}` and `\renewcommand\theequation{A\arabic{equation}}` immediatelt after `\appendix`?

Comment: ```\setcounter{equation}{0}``` solves the problem, thanks @Mico !